# Using some of the custom class property as a unique key to another property(which forms as values) in the same class using dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, data-structures

I have a class type say ValueSetting like below and i am trying to iterate List< ValueSetting > such that for all common entries of param1, param2, param3 in the list i will have to do specific operation for each of param4. let me explain . in the table below, entries with red arrow marks (param1, param2, param3) should be some thing like a key for list< values > of param4(500, 600). So consolidating them

10, foo, abc => (500, 600)

20, boo, abc =>( 500, 600)

30, foo, abc => (500)

So, is this something i can put in dictionary with param1, param2, param3 as key for List< param4 values > ? How is that done? or is there a better way to store them instead of dictionary?

[image]

```
public class ValueSetting 
{  
  public int param1;
  public string param2;
  public string param3;
  public int param4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To structure data the way you ask a [`LINQ ToLookup method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToLookup__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__) can be used. From MSDN:

> The `ToLookup` method returns a `Lookup`, a one-to-many dictionary that maps 
>   keys to collections of values. A `Lookup` differs from a `Dictionary`, 
>   which performs a one-to-one mapping of keys to single values.

To create a `Lookup` using `ToLookup` method we should define:

- `key` class with overridden `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods; this `key` class will define how to group input data;
- `keySelector` that will be used to create keys from input data;
- `elementSelector` that will be used to select values to appropriate keys.

---

**First approach: using anonymous type as a key.**

We can use [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) as a key to create a `Lookup`. `Anonymous types` automatically implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. From MSDN:

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are
>   defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashCode methods of the
>   properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if
>   all their properties are equal.

Here is how we can create a `Lookup` using `anonymous type` as a key:

```
var list = new List<ValueSetting>
{
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 10, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 20, param2 = "boo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 10, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 600},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 20, param2 = "boo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 600},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 30, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
};

var lookup = list.ToLookup(
    vs => new {vs.param1, vs.param2, vs.param3}, // Group key.
    vs => vs.param4);                            // Group values.

foreach (var item in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => ({1})", item.Key, string.Join(", ", item.Select(i => i)));
}
```

This approach is convenient if you are going to use `Lookup` in a single method, because objects of anonymous type cannot be returned from the method and passed to another method as an argument.

---

**Second approach: introducing a key class.**

Another approach is to define a class that will be used as a groupping key. In this class we should override [`GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8) methods. If you use Visual Studio 2015 or later then you can [automatically generate these members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019). Here is how we can define such class:

```
public class Key
{
    public int param1;
    public string param2;
    public string param3;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;
        Key other = (Key) obj;
        Key other = (Key) obj;
        return param1 == other.param1 && 
               string.Equals(param2, other.param2) && 
               string.Equals(param3, other.param3);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = param1;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (param2 != null ? param2.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (param3 != null ? param3.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

And then using this key class we are able to create a `Lookup`:

```
var list = new List<ValueSetting>
{
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 10, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 20, param2 = "boo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 10, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 600},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 20, param2 = "boo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 600},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 30, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
};

ILookup<Key, int> lookup = list.ToLookup(
    vs => new Key {param1 = vs.param1, param2 = vs.param2, param3 = vs.param3}, // Group key.
    vs => vs.param4); // Group values.

foreach (IGrouping<Key, int> item in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2} => ({3})",
        item.Key.param1, item.Key.param2, item.Key.param3,
        string.Join(", ", item.Select(i => i)));
}
```

This approach can be used if you want to return `Lookup` from the method, or pass it as an argument to another method, or store as a property of a class (and in other cases when created `Lookup` must be used outside of the method where it was created).

Comment: Ah very nice usage of `ToLookup`. I thinks its better than using `GroupBy` here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can just use [`System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) to do this:

```
var list = new List<ValueSetting>
{
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 10, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 20, param2 = "boo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 10, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 600},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 20, param2 = "boo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 600},
    new ValueSetting {param1 = 30, param2 = "foo", param3 = "abc", param4 = 500},
};

var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.param1, x.param2, x.param3 });

foreach (var grp in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{grp.Key} => ({string.Join(", ", grp.Select(x => x.param4))})");
}
```

Explanation:

- Group by three fields `param1`, `param2` and `param3` using an anonymous class
- Iterate each `IGrouping<'a, ValueSetting>` group from `IEnumerable<IGrouping<'a, ValueSetting>>` groups.
- Output the key along with the grouped `param4` values joined in a `", "` delimited string using [`System.String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) and [`System.Linq.Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8).

We could also just keep `param4` in the grouped values:

```
var grouped = list
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.param1, x.param2, x.param3 })
    .Select(grp => new { grp.Key, param4 = grp.Select(x => x.param4) });

foreach (var grp in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{grp.Key} => ({string.Join(", ", grp.param4)})");
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ param1 = 10, param2 = foo, param3 = abc } => (500, 600)
{ param1 = 20, param2 = boo, param3 = abc } => (500, 600)
{ param1 = 30, param2 = foo, param3 = abc } => (500)
```